# linux mint 17.3 installed - how to reinstall windows from system recovery

Tags: linux-mint

somebody installed linux mint 17.3 cinnamon 64 bit on my girls new asus f 550z and deleated windows. Theres the system recovery partition, the main partition and a partition with the linux system. 
Now the graphic card doesn't work anymore, its in software rendering mode and she wants to have windows back.

Question: What do I need to do, to reinstall windows from the system recovery partition? (at the moment I don't really care, if I keep the linux or not. But I don't know, if theres a win 8 or a win 10. I don't have experience with linux)

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not so much a Linux question as you do not want to use it. The important question is then if the Windows recovery partition was overwritten when Linux was installed. If it was overwritten - then you need a recovery media to proceed.

If the recovery partition is still available - then we just need to get a little help from the BIOS. Restart the computer and press `F9` *before* the computer boots into Linux. The BIOS should present you with some option and you choose `Windows Setup [EMS Enabled]`.

It does not really matter if it is Windows 8 or 10. The important step is to instruct the BIOS to boot into the recovery partition. And for recent Asus machines this would be `F9`. No Linux knowledge needed.

See this [article](https://neosmart.net/wiki/asus-recovery-disk/) for a quick run-down of the different recovery options based on Windows versions.

**EDIT:** If the previous Windows installation was upgraded from 8 to 10 - then you *might* have problems with the recovery partition. If so download a later version of the [Asus Recovery software](https://www.asus.com/support/faq/1013001).

Comment: Thanks. on the hd, partition 2 is labeled linux filesystem, ext4 mounted as filesystem root. part 3 is linux swap - active. I guess, part 3 is the os, part 2 the files.  If I can boot in the recovery partition:  would I install in partition 2 - what happens to the linux, then? Is it still bootable/usable in case the windows installation doesn't work? or do I create a new partition first (if yes, how?) and install windows in that?

Comment: In your case I would let Windows recovery wipe Linux entirely. That is the easy route. Otherwise you would need to resize the existing partitions and make sure there is clear space for Windows. And after the Windows recovery you might need to reinstall the boot loader to get back into Linux. This is not worth the hassle. If you insist - then I would recommend fixing the current Linux install first.